# Closing winform from button on another winform. Form will not close

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms on my application. I have the main form that opens TopMost, CenterScreen and Maximized. Then I have another form on this screen that pops open  when I press a button. That second screen has a button that navigates to another screen, so when I press that button the second form closes, and the main form is suppose to close as well and the selected sheet open up.

However, the second screen closes fine, but my main screen remains open and active, while the called sheet opens but does not enable.  I track down what was happening and the issue is that form all code runs, but the main screen does not seem to want to close. Here is my code:

```
        Private Sub btnOpenDashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDashboard.Click

    Dim welcomeForm As New frmWelcomePage

    If lblReportTitle.Text = "Employee Dashboard" Then

        Me.Close() 'This works
        welcomeForm.Close() 'This one remains open and active
        Globals.dsbEmployeeBoard.Select() 'This one opens but is not enabled


    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense, why do you instanciate a form never show it and then close it, it won't close if it's has never been opened ! if you somewhere showed it, you can still close it before closing the modal form that opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference of your first form (`Form1`) to the second form (`Form2`), so that in the second form you can close the first form, like this:

```
Public Class Form2 Inherits Form
Private _form1 As Form1

Public Sub New(form1 As Form1)
    Me.Form1 = form1
End Sub
End Class

Private Sub btnOpenDashboard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDashboard.Click
    If lblReportTitle.Text = "Employee Dashboard" Then
        _form1.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then when you instantiate `Form2`, you would pass a reference to `Form1`, like this:

```
Dim form2 As New Form2(Me)
```

Note: `Me` is the instance of `Form1`.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to programming and still working through some of the basic stuff.

Comment: No problem, good luck to you. Learning is what StackOverflow is all about, keep working hard and you will be amazed how far you can go. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your description that you already have a welcome form created and displayed before the form with the button is displayed.

This line of code:
"Dim welcomeForm As New frmWelcomePage"

is creating a *new* copy of the Welcome Page and closing it.

Instead of creating a new one, you need to reference the original one that is open.

If I recall correctly, you should be able to just remove that line and use frmWelcomPage.Close.

Comment: Thanks, when I use the line frmWelcomePage.Close() I get an error saying that Reference to a non shared member requires an object reference. I have no idea what that means